# удаленные blob данные продолжают подтягиваться

Tags: sql, oracle, blob

из БД oracleSQL подтягиваются "невидимые" данные из колонок BLOB. Пришли к выводу, что "невидимые" данные когда-то существовали и были удалены. Перестают подтягиваться только после пересоздания BLOB. А если во вновь созданной BLOB удалить новые записи, то они так же продолжают подтягиваться. Есть ли какой то может признак/механизм или еще-что в самих BLOB, что позволит определить что было удалено.

Comment: судя по удалённому тэгу "java", у вас проблема с клиентом, а не с БД.  Видимо, java (или драйвер на стороне клиента) их закешировала и подтягивает )))  Не знаю, можно ли такого добиться в чистом оракле, напр, заранее открыть селектор блоба на чтение, а потом удалить его из таблицы.